# Wordpress resizing post thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress, resize, thumbnails

I wanna resize post thumbnail in Wordpress. So I use that function: get_the_post_thumbnail($onepost->ID, array(234, 156)); But I recive images with size 300x189. Why is this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You best bet it to add your thumbnail size by using at add_image_size function, then call that new thumnail in your function:

In your functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 234, 156 );
```

In your template file or wherever you're calling the thumbnail:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-thumb' );
```

Note that you will probably have to regenate your thumbnails after you do this as thumbnails are created when you upload the image, thus all images you uploaded won't have this custom thumbnail size.  Here is a good plugin for that:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/